# Barcode scanner Honeywell ms5145 only outputting to terminal

Tags: usb, printing, scanner, barcode

I have this barcode scanner. When I read any barcode (ean-13) it prints this number 056053057052048048051056052053054052050070010. The number is printed only in the terminal. In a text editor or web input it prints nothing.

I use Lubuntu 15.04

The lsusb command shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've got the device configured in **Serial Emulation Mode** but you want it in **Keyboard Emulation Mode**.  The [manual](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/CatalogDocuments/70-79016%20Rev%20G%2012-12.pdf) says you need to refer to the USB section of the *MetroSelect Single-Line Configuration Guide*.

Just to clarify, I believe this is a device configuration issue not a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: @Helda , if the answer worked for you, please click on the tick underneath the numbers to the left of hughs answer to mark it as accepted!